# inject Firebase analytics to apk

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an apk and ipa, I was wondering if it is possible to inject Firebase analytics to them. Similar to other wrapper applications that allow to inject their code into an apk or ipa. Is this possible with Firebase? I have not been able to find information regarding Firebase injection.

Comment: What do you mean by "inject"?  What do you hope to accomplish here that's different than what you see in the Analytics documentation?

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for your response! I have an apk which I dont have access to the code. I would like to add analytics to it and I was hoping there was a way to add basic analytics. I understand since I dont have access to the code and I wont be able to add events, etc. However, as long as I can see session count that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't tell you that it's impossible to add Analytics to an existing APK, but what you're trying to do definitely isn't supported by Firebase.  The only supported course of action is to add the SDK at compile and build time.

If you wanted to add the SDK after the app is built, you would have to go through the trouble of decompiling the APK, modifying the decompiled app components to include the SDK, then rebuild the APK altogether.  There is no way to easily "inject" the SDK into an existing app.

Comment: Thank you for your response @DougStevenson. This answers my question!